# finding all possible permutations of a given ArrayList<String>, and Storing them in global variable

Tags: java, arraylist, global-variables, hashset, recursive-backtracking

In the code given below I am adding the a particular permutation of `ArrayList` in the function `permute` but while printing in the `main` function all possible permutations are not printed. Instead, the same `ArrayList<String>` is printed n! times where n is length of given `ArrayList<String>`.

I am adding the permutations in `set`(my global variable) in `permute` function as `set.add(names)` but while printing it in `main` function it gives output as the same unarranged Arraylist.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Q1 {
    
     static Set<ArrayList<String>> set = new HashSet<>(); ;
     
     
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = in.nextInt();
        
         ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            String temp;
            temp = in.next();
            names.add(temp);
            
        }
        System.out.println(set.size());
        
        permute(names,0,names.size()-1);
        
        System.out.println(set.size());
        
        for(ArrayList<String> i : set) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    
    public static void permute(ArrayList<String> names , int l, int r) {
        
        if(l==r) {
            
            if(set.contains(names)) {
                return;
            }
            set.add((ArrayList<String>)names);
            //System.out.println(names);
        
            return;
            
        }
        
        for(int i=l;i<=r;i++) {
            Collections.swap(names,l ,i);
            permute(names , l+1, r);
            Collections.swap(names,l,i);
        }
        
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are repeatedly adding the same object `names` to `set`. But you need to add a copy of `names`.

```
        set.add((ArrayList<String>)names);
```

→

```
        set.add(new ArrayList<>(names));
```